# How do I make this single variable into a (NameA or Name B or NameC)

Tags: java, string

There is the working code

```
 else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("noclip") && !playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tom" )) {
            PlayerHandler.messageToAll = (playerName
                    + " tried to noclip and has been autobanned!");
            appendToBanned(playerName);
            disconnected = true;
```

since it says does not equal tom, I'm the only one who can use the command. However, I want to add multiple users to this command.

I want to say the following, but it doesn't work... How would I properly say this (java)?

```
 else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("noclip") && !playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tom" || "Tommy" || "Mod Tom" )) {
            PlayerHandler.messageToAll = (playerName
                    + " tried to noclip and has been autobanned!");
            appendToBanned(playerName);
            disconnected = true;
```

Comment: You use some kind of collection. In this specific case, a `HashSet` seems a good option.

Comment: It would be best to have a User/Player object and  playerName.equalsIgnoreCase(player.getName()) or if player.isPlayer(username) .. but to solve your current problem && (playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tom") || playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tommy"))

Comment: I'd recommend checking user rights against Groups rather than users. Then put users into Groups. So you may have a Group "noclippers" and add users to. Then you'd check if the user is in the noclippers Group (and if that group has the right).

Answer (score 2):

In order to simplify the code a bit, I would place the possible username into a `HashSet`.

```
HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
names.addAll("Tom", "Tommy", "Mod Tom");
```

and then I would check:

```
if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("noclip") && !names.contains(playerName)) { .. }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `!playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tom" || "Tommy" || "Mod Tom" ))`. `||` operator is for comparing `boolean`. You can consider the following three approaches:

```
if ( /* Previous conditions && */  (!playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tom") ||
        !playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Tommy") ||
        !playerName.equalsIgnoreCase("Mod Tom")))
    // do things
```

or use a loop with an array:

```
String[] admins = {"Tom", "Tommy", "Mod Tom"};
boolean matches = false;
for (String name : admins)
    if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(playerName))
        matches = true;
if ( /* Previous conditions && */ !matches)
    // do things
```

or use a set:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("Tom");
set.add("Tommy");
set.add("Mod Tom");
if ( /* Previous conditions && */ !set.contains())
    // do things
```